# Unable to access the WCF Service metadata when custom validator is introduced

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a web service(using wsHttpBinding and SSL) developed in Visual Studio 2017. Whenever i introduce the following line, the Web Service just fails and it goes into the "faulted" state.

```
<authentication certificateValidationMode="Custom" customCertificateValidatorType="SampleProject.SampleService.AuthenticationCertificateValidator, SampleProject.SampleService"/>
```

The error message when attempting to "Add Service Reference" on the client side i recieve the following error:

```
There was an error downloading 'https://localhost/SampleService/service'.
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 
'https://localhost/SampleService/service'.
There was no endpoint listening at https://localhost/SampleService/service 
that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address 
or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the 
solution and adding the service reference again.
```

Here is the code relating to the validator.

```
public class AuthenticationCertificateValidator : X509CertificateValidator
{
   string allowedIssuerName;

public AuthenticationCertificateValidator(string allowedIssuerName)
{
    if (allowedIssuerName == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("allowedIssuerName");
    }

    this.allowedIssuerName = allowedIssuerName;
}

public override void Validate(X509Certificate2 certificate)
{
    // Check that there is a certificate.
    if (certificate == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("certificate");
    }

    // Check that the certificate issuer matches the configured issuer.
    if (allowedIssuerName != certificate.IssuerName.Name)
    {
        throw new SecurityTokenValidationException
          ("Certificate was not issued by a trusted issuer");
    }
}
}
```

However the service works fine when i only have the "ChainTrust" line enabled as shown below:

```
<!--certificateValidationMode="Custom" 
       customCertificateValidatorType
       ="SampleProject.SampleService.AuthenticationCertificateValidator, 
        SampleProject.SampleService"/>-->
<authentication certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust" />
```

Ideally i want my service and client to use ChainTrust and also use the custom validator class if that's possible?

Therefore what am i doing wrong regarding configuration? Am i missing something from the config file?

Here is the full Service config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
  <service name="SampleProject.SampleService.SampleService" 
    behaviorConfiguration="SampleService_Behavior">
    <endpoint
      address="https://localhost/SampleService/service"
      binding="wsHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="SampleService_Binding"
      contract="SampleProject.SampleService.ISampleService" />
   <endpoint
      address="https://localhost/SampleService/service/mex"
      binding="mexHttpsBinding"
      contract="IMetadataExchange" />

  </service>
</services>

<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="SampleService_Binding"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" >
      <readerQuotas
        maxDepth="2147483647"
        maxStringContentLength="2147483646"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"  negotiateServiceCredential="true" 
        algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SampleService_Behavior">
      <!--Service metadata is needed for when you have an mex endpoint exposed-->
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpsGetUrl="https://localhost/SampleService/service/mex"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
      <!--The serviceCredentials behavior defines a service certificate
                    which is used by the service to authenticate itself to its
                    clients and to provide message protection. -->
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate
          findValue="SampleServer"
          storeLocation="LocalMachine"
          storeName="My"
          x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
        <clientCertificate>
          <!--<authentication certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust" />-->
          <authentication 
          certificateValidationMode="Custom" 
       customCertificateValidatorType
       ="SampleProject.SampleService.AuthenticationCertificateValidator, 
        SampleProject.SampleService"/>
        </clientCertificate>
      </serviceCredentials>
     </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>

     <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehaviour">
        <webHttp/>
     </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
 </configuration>
```

if someone could assist me that would be much appreciated.

Comment: maybe try removing the httpsGetUrl part?

Comment: I got it working now by introducing a parameter-less constructor in my validator class:

public AuthenticationCertificateValidator(){} but if i want to check the certificate value how would i access it?

Comment: What do you mean by certificate value?

Comment: I mean the client certificate "Subject" and/or "Subject Alternative Name" property values.

Comment: Do you mean on the validate method?

Comment: Yes, how would validate method be invoked if i excluded the parameter-less constructor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187849/discussion-between-mahlatse-and-kp1).